# Replace specific string, and copy the text block below it

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have the two following text files

a.txt:

```
Hello, my name is <name>
and I like flowers.
```

b.txt:

```
Susan
Katie
Caitlynn
```

I want to manipulate this to have the following output in c.txt:

```
Hello, my name is Susan
and I like flowers.

Hello, my name is Katie
and I like flowers.

Hello, my name is Caitlynn
and I like flowers.
```

and so on and so forth.

I can replace them in one instance, but don't know how to continuously read from b.txt to continue replacing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} 
     {for (i in a) { s=$0; sub(/<name>/, i, s); print s}}' b.txt a.txt
Hello, my name is Caitlynn
Hello, my name is Susan
Hello, my name is Katie
```

---

**Update:** Based on edited question:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} /<name>/{curLine=$0; getline nextLine;
  for (i in a) {s=curLine; sub(/<name>/, i, s); print s; print nextLine}}' b.txt a.txt
Hello, my name is Caitlynn
and I like flowers.
Hello, my name is Susan
and I like flowers.
Hello, my name is Katie
and I like flowers.
```

Comment: This may do: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} {for (i in a) {$NF=i;print}}' `

Comment: Thanks, Yes that will certainly work if  `<name>` is always the last field

Comment: @anubhava, when I run your `awk` command it prints the names in reverse order.  Any idea why?

Comment: It is not reverse order, it is just no order since associate order doesn't maintain insertion order in awk. If OP wants original order I can add a fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution for first version of the question

Here is a `sed` solution:

```
$ sed -r '1{h;d}; G; s/(.*)\n(.*)<name>(.*)/\2\1\3/' a.txt b.txt
Hello, my name is Susan
Hello, my name is Katie
Hello, my name is Caitlynn
```

#### How it works

- `1{h;d}`

  The first line that `sed` sees is from `a.txt`.  This saves that line in the hold space and then skips to start over with the next line.
- `G`

  The second and all subsequent lines come from `b.txt`.  For each such line, this command appends the hold space to that line.  After this executes, the pattern space has the name (from `b.txt`) followed by a newline, followed by the the line from `a.txt`.
- `s/(.*)\n(.*)<name>(.*)/\2\1\3/`

  This rearranges the pattern space, putting the name where it should be.

#### Solution for second version of the question

```
$ sed -r '1{h;d}; 2{H;d}; G; s/(.*)\n(.*)<name>(.*)/\2\1\3/' a2.txt b.txt
Hello, my name is Susan
and I like flowers.
Hello, my name is Katie
and I like flowers.
Hello, my name is Caitlynn
and I like flowers.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try sed + bash loop:

```
for x in $(cat b.txt); do sed -e "s/<name>/$x/" a.txt; done
```

If you need additional line between sentences

```
for x in $(cat b.txt); do sed -e "s/<name>/$x/" a.txt; echo ""; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{tmplt=tmplt $0 ORS; next} {block=tmplt; sub(/<name>/,$0,block); print block}' a.txt b.txt
Hello, my name is Susan
and I like flowers.

Hello, my name is Katie
and I like flowers.

Hello, my name is Caitlynn
and I like flowers.
```

Answer (score 0):

**using sed tactically with its `e command` as follows**

```
 sed 's#.*#sed "s/\\(.*\\)<name>\\(.*\\)/\\n\\1&\\2/" a.txt #e' b.txt > c.txt
```

where `c.txt` is your new file with expected results

results

```
Hello, my name is Susan
and I like flowers.

Hello, my name is Katie
and I like flowers.

Hello, my name is Caitlynn
and I like flowers.
```